# Replace capital letter with underscore + lowercase letter in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to use RegEx in Java to replace all capital letters with an underscore and the same letter only lowercase?

Example:
`getSpecialString` -> `get_special_string`

Comment: This is not a Java related question. You should follow this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: @cagirici why is this not a Java related question? Clearly you can't do what he's asking with pure regex!

Comment: @MikyDinescu Actually, you can do this with pure regex with some tools. That doesn't mean that the `java` tag should be removed!

Comment: @Jerry I wasn't aware that you could perform case conversions using regular expressions. But just re-reading the Java docs it seems that's not supported in Java. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @MikyDinescu This questions is surely about coding in java. But it would be Java-related if the question was "how to write this expression in java." But OP asks how to do something using regular expression. Same thing as "is there a way to translate an English text to French and print it using Java?" Here, Java can be any programming language.

Comment: @cagirici - I agree that the question could have been phrased way better but I have to disagree with you saying the the OP is asking `how to do something using regular expression`. To quote the OP, he asks: `Is there a way to use RegEx in Java to replace all capital letters`

Comment: I've changed the question. Sorry, guys. I'm not in the best shape.

Comment: @MikyDinescu I don't think you can in Java. I was only pointing out that you could do it depending on the tools you used. Surely, it would have caused more confusion if the Java tag was not there.

Comment: @Jerry - thanks for clarifying.. and I learned something in the process too :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just try with:

```
"getSpecialString".replaceAll("([A-Z])", "_$1").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thanks. I love it how all people are bashing me just because I couldn't find the first letter identifier in the docs.

Comment: I love $ regex pattern

Comment: @assylias What first `_` ?

Comment: @dragostis No one bashed you. Ask your question clearly. And _show_ some effort if you've made any.

Comment: Okay. Next time I'll post the question after it's fully developed. Sorry for posting it like that. Peace, bro.

Comment: Also consider using `((?!<_)([A-Z]))` instead if you want `get_Special_string` to change into `get_special_string`

Answer (score 1):

This could also work using Regex!

```
"MyCamelCase".replaceAll(/(?<!^)[A-Z]/g, (match) => `_${match}`).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a snakeCase method in [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library:

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        U.snakeCase("getSpecialString"); // -> get_special_string
    }
}
```